# html page takes over time for load the content

Tags: html, coldfusion

I've used one static cfm page and it's has a single select query for showing a above 3000 records(without pagination). When i am try to view that page in FF its takes the 15 sec for shows the content. If any way(without pagination) to reduce the browser loading time?

Comment: If the recordset continues to grow, eventually you will overwhelm the browser, no matter what methods you use.

Comment: Use the Developer Tools or Firebug to look at the network request for the page. Is the request actually taking 15 seconds, or is it taking a fraction of a series on then takes 15 seconds to render to the screen? The answer will help identify where the perceived problem is actually coming from. Also, please show some code where you are outputting the query results so we can make educated suggestions for resolution.

Comment: I have faced this problem where ALL the records have to be displayed on single page. Assuming your SQL is optimized and issue is with rendering of so many records and if you are using html tables, trick would be make them fixed width, so that browser do not have to calculate width for each cell as it is rendered (James Mohler already pointed this in his answer). Just wanted to add my 2 cents having gone through this kind of problem in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Optimize the `SELECT` query

- Only select columns you need.
- Avoid wildcards (*) in the `SELECT` clause
- Don't join unnecessary tables.

You can also consider loading content dynamically via `ajax`.

Without seeing your code (or example code), we can't provide anything specifically tailored to your implementation of the query.

Comment: It will take less time to run the database query, which will reduce some of the page load time. Selecting 3000 results is definitely an opportunity for optimization. Especially without pagination.

Comment: I took his question to mean just rendering the HTML was taking 15 seconds, but I may have been thinking too simply

Comment: No problem. I started to second-guess if ColdFusion's database performance would even happen between the server requests. I don't use ColdFusion much.

Comment: I think taking 15 seconds to render the html is a reasonable assumption.  In fact, I'm tempted to downvote this answer because the first paragraph has nothing to do with the question as it was asked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a page that uses that uses AngularJS to show the table. Then populate the table via an AJAX call to get JSON.
2. Use fixed table layout so that the browser does not have to re-flow the content as it loads.
3. Don't load the data into a table at all. Do the layout with div's and span's

Comment: The question makes no mention of an html table.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially

```
<cfflush>
```

the content, so it will start sending the response to the browser straight away, rather than building the entire page, then pushing the response back

Answer (score 0):

Some other solutions are better options, especially for long term scalability and maintenance.  However, if you're looking for a quick solution for now you could try breaking it up into a series of HTML tables.  Every 500 records or so add this:

```
  </table>
  <cfflush>
  <table...
```

This will insure that html rendered so far is sent to the browser (via the cfflush) while ColdFusion continues to work on the rest.  Meanwhile, by closing out the table before doing so you're allowing the browser to properly render that block of the content in full without risking it waiting for the remainder.

This is a patch, and something you should only do until you can put a more involved solution (such as [JQGrid](http://www.trirand.com)) in place.